# Replace a substring of a given length after a spefic piece of text

Tags: javascript, replace, automation, substring, testcomplete

I'm stuck :) Using javascript.
I get an output from an instrument of which below is a partial outtake. I need to verify this data.
On the line beginning 'MSH', after instrument field is a date and time
`20210204220807+00:00`
This repeats several time in the output and I want to strip it out of the string.

I will have the system date and time to the minute. For example 202102042208 . How can I use this to remove the whole text everywhere it appears? So replace 202102042208 + the next 8 characters.

No idea how I can do this? Any help is appreciated

```
MSH|^~\&|New1|| Instrument 1||**20210204220807+00:00**||RSP^K11^RSP_K11|547CwlxiBkSMM9D2tSU+pw|P|2.5.1||||||UNICODE UTF-8|||LAB-27R^wegewg
MSA|AA|1234
QAK|query1234|OK|INIBAR^^99ROC
QPD|INIBAR^^99ROC|query1234|Sample1|50001|1|||||SERPLAS^^99ROC|^^99ROC|R
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `^(MSH.*)202102042208.{8}`

- `^(MSH.*)`, capture match string start from `MSH` to `**`, it will be used for replacement or `$1`
- `.{8}` match any characters with length of 8

```js
var str = `MSH|^~\&|New1|| Instrument 1||**20210204220807+00:00**||RSP^K11^RSP_K11|547CwlxiBkSMM9D2tSU+pw|P|2.5.1||||||UNICODE UTF-8|||LAB-27R^wegewg
MSA|AA|1234
QAK|query1234|OK|INIBAR^^99ROC
QPD|INIBAR^^99ROC|query1234|Sample1|50001|1|||||SERPLAS^^99ROC|^^99ROC|R 
MSH|^~\&|New1|| Instrument 1||**20210204220807+00:00**||RSP^K11^RSP_K11|547CwlxiBkSMM9D2tSU+pw|P|2.5.1||||||UNICODE UTF-8|||LAB-27R^wegewg`

str = str.replace(/^(MSH.*)202102042208.{8}/gm, '$1Date_Removed')
console.log(str)
```